# How to handle timeout in python process?

Tags: python, signals

Please check below simple code then help to answer my question.

```
import signal
def task(*args, **kwargs):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal_to_exception)
    while True:
        try:
            signal.alarm(3)
            # do some business
            signal.alarm(0)
        except AlarmException:
            signal.alarm(0)
            continue
```

The task will be run by a python process. The code

do some business

May hang due to IO wait or some else.

I added the signal model to make send Alarm signal every 3 seconds. If business done within 3 seconds.  Then reset the alarm to 0.

The signal_to_exception will transfer alarm signal to an exception.

So my question is

Is this the right way to control timeout in process?

Will this cause any trouble?